# Masonry shows at the bottom of a page when using tab content menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am new in coding. Please don't blame me, if i failed with code.

**The problem**

I am using Masonry and tab content menu plugins. In first, active menu, content displays perfectly, but when i am clicking second or third menu item, content displays at the bottom of the page (or there, where last "item" at the first content menu placed).

Click [here](http://bandymas.mooo.com/re/) **for PRESETATION - DEMO.**

**Tab menu:**

```
<div class="filtras-meniu">
   <div class="filtras-meniu-vieta">
      <div class="tabs">
    <p>
     <button class="btn active" data-tab="#tab1">Visi renginiai</button>
     <button class="btn" data-tab="#tab2">Būsimi renginiai</button>
     <button class="btn" data-tab="#tab3">Jau įvykę renginiai</button>
    </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Masonry item**

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="mda">
    <a href="#">
       <div class="item-overlay">
       <div class="item-hover"><img style="width:128px; height:142px; border:none;" src="img/daugiau.png" /></div>
   </div>
      <img style="border:none;" src="http://polifonija.lt/images/banners/18944.png" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <span>VOKIŠKASIS REQUIEM</span>
  <h3>Kovo 3, 2014</h3>
   <div class="reng-linija"></div>
 <div class="reng-kita">
  <img src="img/comment.png" />
  <b>28 komentarai</b>
  <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.item {
  display: block; float: left; width: 300px; margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
  -webkit-transition: left .4s ease-in-out, top .4s ease-in-out .4s;
  -moz-transition: left .4s ease-in-out, top .4s ease-in-out .4s;
  -ms-transition: left .4s ease-in-out, top .4s ease-in-out .4s;
  -o-transition: left .4s ease-in-out, top .4s ease-in-out .4s;
  transition: left .4s ease-in-out, top .4s ease-in-out .4s;
  background:white;
  -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #bebebe;
  -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #bebebe;
  box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #bebebe;
 }

.itemai { position:absolute; margin:70px 0px; }
.item img { float:left; margin:15px 15px; width: 270px; height: auto; }
.item span { float:left; margin:0px 15px; width:270px; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px; font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration:none; color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85); }
.item h3 { float:left; margin:5px 15px; width:270px; height:20px; font-weight:normal; font-family:arial; font-size:10px; color:grey; }
.reng-linija { float:left; margin:0px 15px; width:270px; height:1px; background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10); }
.reng-kita { float:left; margin:0px 15px; width:270px; height:50px; }
.reng-kita img { float:left; margin:12px 0px; width:25px; height:24px; border:none; }
.reng-kita b { float:left; margin:17px 10px; font-weight:normal; font-family:arial; font-size:11px; }
.fb-like { float:right; margin:14px -15px; }
```

**Display**

```
<div id="content" class="container clearfix">

<div class="renginiu-filtras">
  <?php include 'filtras-meniu.php'; ?>
</div>

<div class="itemai">

 <div class="tabs-content">

   <div class="tabs-pane active" id="tab1">
    <?php include 'renginiai-all.php'; ?>
   </div>

   <div class="tabs-pane" id="tab2">
    <?php include 'renginiai-busimi.php'; ?>
   </div>

   <div class="tabs-pane" id="tab3">
    <?php include 'renginiai-ivyke.php'; ?>
   </div>

  </div>

 </div>

</div>
```

Thank to all of you for any answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 <button class="btn active" data-tab="#tab1" onClick="$('#content').masonry().layout()">Visi renginiai</button>
 <button class="btn" data-tab="#tab2" onClick="$('#content').masonry().layout()">Būsimi renginiai</button>
 <button class="btn" data-tab="#tab3" onClick="$('#content').masonry().layout()">Jau įvykę renginiai</button>
```

Or call this whenever a TAB is changed. Or even better call it on tabbys change callbacks:

```
tabby.init({
    toggleActiveClass: 'active', // Class added to active toggle elements
    contentActiveClass: 'active', // Class added to active tab content areas
    initClass: 'js-tabby', // Class added to <html> element when initiated
    //here
    callbackBefore: function () {
         $('#content').masonry().layout()
    }, // Function that's run before tab content is toggled
   //or here:
    callbackAfter: function () {
         $('#content').masonry().layout()
   } // Function that's run after tab content is toggled
});
```

I'm not keen with tabby (not even sure this is the right tabby) so just try it out and see what happens.

Works for me, when i fire it up in the firbug console on your demo page.

Comment: hmm, none of theese works. Both freeze tab plugin :/

Comment: Hmm, then maybe you should isolate the issue with a fiddle or plunker and minimal code. It's always hard to fix something on an existing demo page. Open firebug when you are on your page and enter the call to layout in the command line of the console after you changed a tab. You will see that all tiles slide into the proper pages. You just have to find the right moment to call it.

Comment: Hm.. thanks for your answers, but like i said, i am not good at coding.. i dont even have a clue to how to fix this problem.. i think, i'll go for static menu with hyperlinks.. thanks again!

Comment: OMG! callbackAfter method worked! I dont know why it did not worked couple of hours ago, but now it works! Thanks! <3